# Django Database settings

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings, django-database

I've two databases in my Django app, BUT with different IP's, ie HOST are different.

```
    'default': { # This is the DB in the same machine itself.
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': 'sortation_gor',              
        'USER': 'vms_gor',
        'PASSWORD': 'apj0702',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'a1': { # This is in another machine with IP listed below.
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'a1',              
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.27',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

When I run my code, and I try to save data in `a1` DB, it returns me `500 error`. But if I've the DB in the same machine in which the app is running, it works fine. **What can be the problem?**

**Q2)** In my templates, I've a check field that :-

```
{% if admin_permission %}
   <li id='main_menu_config'><a href="{% url 'configuration' %}"><span class="icon-cog icon-white"></span> Configuration</a></li
{% endif %}
```

Although the `Configuration` tab is not visible, but I can still navigate to the URL(provided I know the exact URL) even if I'm not admin.

**How can this be solved.**

**Routers.py file**

```
class GorRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    gor application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read gor models go to gor_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'gor_data':
            return 'default'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write gor models go to gor_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'gor_data':
            return 'default'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the gor app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'gor_data' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'gor_data':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        """
        Make sure the gor app only appears in the 'gor_db'
        database.
        """
        if db == 'default':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'gor_data'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'gor_data':
            return False
        return None



class A1Router(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.app_label == 'a1_data':
            return 'a1'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.app_label == 'a1_data':
            return 'a1'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):

        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'a1_data' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'a1_data':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        """
        Make sure the aramex app only appears in the 'aramex_db'
        database.
        """
        if db == 'a1':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'a1_data'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'a1_data':
            return False
        return None
```

Comment: Split your questions into two separate questions. They are unrelated and combining both here has a high likelihood of getting this questions closed as too broad.

Comment: Debug is already Enabled. All it returns is `500 Internal Server Error. Contact the Administrator.`

Comment: Can you paste your DatabaseRouter please?

Comment: regarding the first question - have you tried connecting to the DB without django? i.e. open a shell and try connecting with it. If you succeed, it's a problem with django. If not, it's probably a problem with the host which might have some configuration preventing remote connections entirely

Comment: Ohh...let me try that.